# wpf bind usercontrol property to datacontext of mainwondow

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a usercontrol (a label and a textbox. I would like to bind the Text of the user control to the property Name from an DTO class Employee ( Employee.Name) where binding is set in the mainwindow, outside of the usercontrol. This is my UserControl ( **look at the controls label and text**)

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestCompany.controls.textEdit"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestCompany.controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Name="label" Content="{Binding Caption}" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="35" FontWeight="Light"/>
    <TextBox Name="textbox" Text="{Binding Text}" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="33" Background="White"  />
</Grid>
```

**Caption** is the title of the control and **Text** displays the value

And here is the code behind

```
public string Caption
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(CaptionProperty, value);                
        }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty CaptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Caption", typeof(string), typeof(textEdit), null);


    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);                
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);                
        }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(textEdit), null);
```

Now in the main window, this is how I use my custom control

```
<controls:textEdit Caption="Name" Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,20,0" />
```

Then in the mainwindow, from the list of Employees, I take the selected one and I assign it to the context

```
this.DataContext = EmployeeObject; // Name = "Joe"
```

But the Text property of the usercontrol does not display "Joe". Even the setter of the property is never called. The weird this is that if within the constructor of my usercontrol I don't assign UserControl.Datacontext to this

```
DataContext = this; // within the constructor of UserControl
```

then even the Label control is empty (the label control is linked to the Caption dependency property). I have looked at countless similar issues on stackOverflow and else where. ( RelativeSource Self etc...). Nothing works...The Text property of my user control does not display value from the Datacontext set in the mainwindow...

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding to UserControl DependencyProperty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985382/binding-to-usercontrol-dependencyproperty); read also comments about DataContext under accepted answer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I applied the solution provided there. The text correctly display the value. But the label is now empty

Comment: Can you include the code when you created the EmployeeObject?

Comment: It is a very simple code: var EmployeeObject = DAL.fetch("empID");
fecth is a call to backend and it returns a Emp object with specified empID. classic stuff.

Comment: I just want to make sure that the object has its property set before it was assigned and implementing INPC. Is it?

Comment: Yes Name has its value correctly set. I can see it while debugging

Comment: You see, Text property is supposed to take its value from EmployeeObject.Name. So DataContext of UserControl must be correctly set. But Caption property (the label control) has its value hardcoded in the mainwindow (see above in the question --> Caption="Name" where I insert the usercontrol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` to that of your main window, and the `DataContext`of the `Grid` to the `UserControl`. That means that when the `UserControl`is looking for its data, it looks in the DataContext it inherits from `MainWindow`, but when your `Grid` looks for its data, it looks inside the `UserControl`. You do it like this:

```
<UserControl ... 
     d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
     x:Name="ThisControl">

<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ThisControl}">
...
```

See http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html.

Comment: Thanks. I have done what you said. I defined a DataContextin the Grid, within the UserControl. Still the Text correctly binds. But the label is still empty.

Comment: Great. That article was what really gave me a way in to understanding DataContext.