# DataContext binding in UserControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datacontext

Trying to get DataContext in UserControl.

My
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkKLu.png)

I have the model Car

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AutoShop.MVVM.Model
{
    class Car : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }


        private string _Model;
        public string Model
        {
            get
            {
                return _Model;
            }
            set
            {
                _Model = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _Mark;
        public string Mark
        {
            get
            {
                return _Mark;
            }
            set
            {
                _Mark = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private float _Volume;
        public float Volume
        {
            get
            {
                return _Volume;
            }
            set
            {
                _Volume = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private int _DateOfIssue;
        public int DateOfIssue
        {
            get
            {
                return _DateOfIssue;
            }
            set
            {
                _DateOfIssue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public enum EngineTypes { 
            DISEL,
            PETROL
        };

        private EngineTypes _EngineType;
        public EngineTypes EngineType
        {
            get
            {
                return _EngineType;
            }
            set
            {
                _EngineType = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _ImageUrl;

        public string ImageUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return _ImageUrl;
            }
            set
            {
                _ImageUrl = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public Car()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And I have main view model

```
using AutoShop.MVVM.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace AutoShop.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

        public HomeViewModel HomeVM; 

        private object _CurrentPage;
        public object CurrentPage
        {
            get
            {
                return _CurrentPage;
            }
            set
            {
                _CurrentPage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private List<Car> _Cars;

        public List<Car> Cars
        {
            get
            {
                return _Cars;
            }
            set
            {
                _Cars = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Cars = new List<Car>() {
                new Car
                {
                    Mark = "Audi",
                    Model = "asdf",
                    Volume = 1.4F,
                    DateOfIssue = 2019,
                    EngineType = Car.EngineTypes.DISEL,
                    ImageUrl = "img/img"
                },
                new Car
                {
                    Mark = "Moto",
                    Model = "asdf",
                    Volume = 1.4F,
                    DateOfIssue = 2019,
                    EngineType = Car.EngineTypes.DISEL,
                    ImageUrl = "img/img"
                },
                new Car
                {
                    Mark = "Some",
                    Model = "asdf",
                    Volume = 1.4F,
                    DateOfIssue = 2019,
                    EngineType = Car.EngineTypes.DISEL,
                    ImageUrl = "img/img"
                }
            };


            HomeVM = new HomeViewModel();
            CurrentPage = HomeVM;

        }
    }
}
```

I need to display cars on the `ProductPage.xaml` and I do it by the next way

```
<UserControl x:Class="AutoShop.MVVM.View.ProductPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AutoShop.MVVM.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             >
    <StackPanel Background="#fff">
        <WrapPanel>
            <Grid Width="200px" Margin="30 0 0 0">
                <TextBox x:Name="field4" Tag="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Learning\Весенний семестр\ООТП\AutoShop\AutoShop\Images\u.png" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}" />
                <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" Text="Марка" Padding="20 10 0 0">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Fonts/#Montserrat Light" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ccc" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=field4}" Value="">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Width="200px" Margin="30 0 0 0">
                <TextBox x:Name="field7" Tag="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Learning\Весенний семестр\ООТП\AutoShop\AutoShop\Images\u.png" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}" />
                <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" Text="username" Padding="20 10 0 0">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Fonts/#Montserrat Light" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ccc" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=field7}" Value="">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Width="200px" Margin="30 0 0 0">
                <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTheme}" SelectedIndex="0">
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <TextBlock Text="asdasdasd" />
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <TextBlock Text="fsdfsd" />
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
            </Grid>
        </WrapPanel>
        <Grid Height="400">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsWrapper" ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Margin="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Height="279">
                                <Grid Height="279" Width="200">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}" Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0 10 0 0"  />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, StringFormat='Name: {0}'}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,120,0,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Mark, StringFormat='Rating: {0}' }" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0 180 0 0" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Model, StringFormat='Category: {0}'}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,200,0,0" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Volume, StringFormat='Price: {0}'}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,160,0,0" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DateOfIssue, StringFormat='Description: {0}'}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,140,0,0" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And it the `MainForm.xaml` I added `ProductPage.xaml`

```
<ContentControl Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
```

The problem is that nothing is being outputted, I think it might be due to the loss of context. How do I properly pass the context to UserControl (ProductPage.xaml)?
[ProductPage.xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhtzD.png)

Update:
[I set DataContext for MainWindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UAHc.png)

And DataContext working becouse `{Binding CurrentPage}` is working, but binding on Cars field is not working

Comment: are you getting any errors in the output window?

Comment: @Default No, I expect items on the my app, but there are nothing

https://prnt.sc/123as04

DataContext is working, becouse my View is loaded (ProductPage.xaml)

Comment: Sorry, I meant  [the output window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/output-window?view=vs-2019) in Visual Studio, showing status messages. WPF is fairly good at showing a lot of information there. you can search in that window after "ERROR".

Comment: hm.. I think I see your problem. see if [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985382/binding-to-usercontrol-dependencyproperty) would help you

Comment: You have `MainViewModel` in the DataContext of the Window.
It is not clear from your code how UserControl is used in the Window layout.
Please show this, as it may be important in understanding the cause of the problem.

Comment: To understand why, add `<TextBlock Text ="{Binding}"/>` to the StackPanel as the first element (before the WrapPanel).
And let us know what this TextBlock will display.

Answer (score 0):

1.find the MainForm.xaml.cs

2.find ctor

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //set the MainForm DataContext
    DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

3.you should add ContentControl.DataTemplate to show your HomeViewModel

----20210427 update

Here demo i make, project name is WpfApp4

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:WpfApp4.Views"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:WpfApp4.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCarViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedCarViewModel}">
                <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <!--Style your product page here-->
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:CarViewModel}">
                        <UniformGrid Columns="2">
                            <TextBlock Text="Name"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Volume"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Volume}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Price"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}"/>
                        </UniformGrid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            </ContentControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApp4.ViewModels
{
    class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<CarViewModel> ItemsSource { get; } = new ObservableCollection<CarViewModel>();

        private CarViewModel selectedCarViewModel;

        public CarViewModel SelectedCarViewModel
        {
            get { return this.selectedCarViewModel; }
            set { SetProperty(ref this.selectedCarViewModel, value); }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            ItemsSource.Add(new CarViewModel() { Name = "BMW", Volume = 10, Price = 100 });
            ItemsSource.Add(new CarViewModel() { Name = "Toyota", Volume = 5, Price = 80 });
            ItemsSource.Add(new CarViewModel() { Name = "Benz", Volume = 20, Price = 150 });

            // don't let view binding null value, so here initialze property "SelectedCarViewModel"
            this.selectedCarViewModel = ItemsSource[0];
        }
    }
}
```

CarViewModel.cs

```
namespace WpfApp4.ViewModels
{
    class CarViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set { SetProperty(ref this.name, value); }
        }

        private float volume;

        public float Volume
        {
            get { return this.volume; }
            set { SetProperty(ref this.volume, value); }
        }

        private decimal price;

        public decimal Price
        {
            get { return this.price; }
            set { SetProperty(ref this.price, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace WpfApp4.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T t, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(t, value))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                t = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited queshion. DataContext is setted, but I forgot mention this

Comment: I'm edit my answer, you can build the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `Window.Resources`. Of course `DataContext` must be set for the `MainForm`.

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xmlnsForVewModel:MainViewModel}">
            <ProductPage/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

and if for `ProductPage` `HomeViewModel` supposed to be a `DataContext`, then `HomeViewModel` has to have `Cars` property, not `MainViewModel`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot mention than page changing is working. I edited the queshion. Check please. CurrentPage binding for ContentControl is working, but bundings not work in the ProductPage.xaml although in theory they have the same context

Comment: @dotsqlcode Will `ProductPage` also be shown? Are you sure you don't set `DataContext` in code behind of `UserControl`?